# Get the field list of flat file connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, ssis

How to write a function (external function, c#, f# or powershell script, etc)

```
List<string> GetFields(string ssisPackageName, string fileSourceName);
```

to get the field list of a SSIS package? Since the package is an Xml file, can xquery be used to get the list?

Or even better, get more information,

```
class Field 
{ 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string Type { get; set; } 
}
List<Field> GetFields(string ssisPackageName, string fileSourceName);
```

Comment: The desire is to retrieve the column definition for a particular flat file connection manager? I would think your `Field` class does not sufficiently represent the complexity of data typing. If it's a string, is it ANSI or Unicode? Unicode, 8 or 16? etc

Answer (score 0):

@billinkc is right, you should keep data typing issues in mind.  That said, you could at best retrieve the Code Page and Unicode values for the Flat File Connection Manager itself.  The following code should get you started, where you might need some lookups for the code page and data type attributes.

```
string path = @"MyPathTo\Package.dtsx";
XNamespace dts = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

// get all connections
var connections = from ele in doc.Descendants(dts + "ConnectionManager")
                  where ele.Attributes(dts + "ObjectName").Count() != 0
                  select ele;

foreach (var connection in connections)
{
    // look for your flat file connection
    if (connection.Attribute(dts + "ObjectName").Value == "Flat File Connection Manager")
    {
        var connectionDetails = connection.Element(dts + "ObjectData").Element(dts + "ConnectionManager");
        Console.WriteLine("CodePage: " + connectionDetails.Attribute(dts + "CodePage").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Unicode: " + connectionDetails.Attribute(dts + "Unicode").Value);
        var columnList = connection.Descendants(dts + "FlatFileColumn");
        foreach (var column in columnList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Column name: " + column.Attribute(dts + "ObjectName").Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Column type: " + column.Attribute(dts + "DataType").Value);
        }
    }
}
```